# How do I exclude capitalizing specific words in a String?

Tags: java, string

I'm new to programming, and here I'm required to capitalise the user's input, which excludes certain words.

For example, if the input is 
*THIS IS A TEST*  I get  *This Is A Test*

However, I want to get **This is a Test** format

```
String s = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
String wordSplit[] = s.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\s");       
String[] t = {"is","but","a"};

        for(int i=0;i<wordSplit.length;i++){
            if(wordSplit[i].equals(t))
                sb.append(wordSplit[i]).append(" ");
            else
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(wordSplit[i].charAt(0))).append(wordSplit[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
```

This is the closest I have gotten so far but I seem to be unable to exclude capitalising the specific words.

Comment: You're checking if a String in `wordSplit` equals() *an array of Strings, `t`*. Don't you want to check every word in `wordSplit` against every word in `t`?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention. But I'm unsure on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing each word to the entire array. Java does not disallow this, but it does not really make a lot of sense. Instead, you *could* loop each word in the array and compare those, but that's a bit lengthy in code, and also not very fast if the array of words gets bigger.

Instead, I'd suggest creating a `Set` from the array and checking whether it `contains` the word:

```
String[] t = {"is","but","a"};
Set<String> t_set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(t));
...
    if (t_set.contains(wordSplit[i]) {
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution! I had tried using a HashMap earlier, but I guess that wasn't the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing the iteration once. Just do it again; iterate through every String in `t` for each String in `wordSplit`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordSplit.length; i++){
  boolean found = false;

  for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {              
    if(wordSplit[i].equals(t[j])) {
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if (found) { /* do your stuff */ }
  else { }
}
```

Comment: And how to handle the `else` case? (Not saying that it's not possible this way, but the answer is a bit incomplete)

Comment: @tobias_k I see your point, and I agree at this point it makes more sense to use `.contains()`

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution! I tried using a nested loop just now, but I missed out the boolean part.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (as pointed out by @sleepToken) is that

```
if(wordSplit[i].equals(t))
```

is checking to see if the current word is equal to the *array* containing your keywords.

Instead what you want to do is to check whether the array *contains* a given input word, like so:

```
if (Arrays.asList(t).contains(wordSplit[i].toLowerCase()))
```

Note that there is no "case sensitive" `contains()` method, so it's important to convert the word in question into lower case before searching for it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for providing the solution! I would also accept this answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

First of all right method which is checking if the word contains in array.

```
contains(word) {
  for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
   if ( word.equals(arr[i])) {
   return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then change your condition `wordSplit[i].equals(t)` to `contains(wordSplit[i]`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

To check the words to exclude `java.util.ArrayList.contains()` method would be a better choice.

The below expression checks if the exclude list contains the word and if not capitalises the first letter:

```
tlist.contains(x) ? x : (x = x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1)))
```

The expression is also corresponds to:

```
if(tlist.contains(x)) {    // ?
    x = x;   // do nothing
} else {    // :
    x = x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1);
}
```

or:

```
if(!tlist.contains(x)) {
    x = x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1);
}
```

If you're allowed to use java 8:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
String wordSplit[] = s.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\s");  
List<String> tlist = Arrays.asList("is","but","a");
String result = Stream.of(wordSplit).map(x -> 
    tlist.contains(x) ? x : (x = x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1)))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
This is a Test
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not using java 8. But what is the ? in the above expression for?

Comment: It's not related with java 8. It is just a `if/else`. Stream part is java 8. I'm adding some explanation for `?`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing with each word to ignore in your code in this line `if(wordSplit[i].equals(t))`

You can do something like this as below:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "THIS IS A TEST";
        String[] ignore = {"is","but","a"};

        List<String> toIgnoreList = Arrays.asList(ignore);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s1 : s.split(" ")) {
            if(!toIgnoreList.contains(s1.toLowerCase())) {
                result.append(s1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())
                        .append(s1.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                        .append(" ");
            } else {
                result.append(s1.toLowerCase())
                        .append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Result: This is a Test
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for providing the solution! I'm still a beginner and not sure what a few of the functions are. But I'll try to find out. Thanks!